# Links on maps, do not work

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an app with an integrated map using the Google Maps v3 API. In the map I show some markers with an infowiew with the client's name, his address and a link to establish the route.

The link once clicked should go to the native application of Google Maps, but it does not respond. The same happens with other links of the markers proper of google, like gas stations, businesses etc ...

I attach the method that loads the map, the bookmarks, the infowindows and the one that should open the native application of google maps.

<--Edit--->
The core app it´s html, css, javascript and jquery. It doesn´t android or ios native.

function initMap() {

```
    // Origin, could be latlng or ZipCode
    var pointOrigin = new google.maps.LatLng(itemsPosition[0].latitud, itemsPosition[0].longitud);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        // Map
        center: pointOrigin
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(itemsPosition[0].latitud, itemsPosition[0].longitud),
        icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png",
        map: map
    });

    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(items[i].latitud, items[i].longitud),
            icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png",
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                marker.setAnimation(null);

                infowindow.setContent("<div id='content'><h4>" + items[i].name + "</h4>" + items[i].dir + "<a id='ruta' href='" + showMap(items[i].latitud + "," + items[i].longitud) + "'>Ver Ruta</a></div>");

                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

    // open  navigator or  native Maps App
    function openMaps(latitud, longitud) {
        window.open(showMap(latitud + "," + longitud), '_system');
    }

    // url changes according  to device
    showMap = function(q) {
        var device = navigator.userAgent;
        var q = q.replace(/\s/g, "+");

        var url = "http://maps.google.com?saddr=" + itemsPosition[0].latitud + ',' + itemsPosition[0].longitud + "&daddr=" + q;

        if (device.match(/Iphone/i) || device.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)) {
            url = 'http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=' + q
        } else if (device.match(/Android/i)) {
            url = "geo:0,0?q=" + q;
        } else if (device.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
            url = "maps:" + q;
        }

        return url;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in case of android:--

You should create an Intent object with a geo-URI:

`String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Is a Hybrid app, so, it´s for ios, windows and android. The core it´s html, css and javascript with jquery.